# Trouble printing NSDate returned from formatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I want to see what is getting stored in an `NSDate`, so I am using `NSLog`, but it's showing `(null)`, whereas if I print the string `stf2`, it's showing the proper value.

```
           NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

            NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

    NSString *stf2 = [[pact.date componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"date %@",stf2);

            NSDate *date_ = [formatter dateFromString:stf2];
            pact.date = [formatter1 stringFromDate:date_];
            NSLog(@"date %@",[NSDate date_]);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the contents of `stf2`.

Comment: Can you show how you've configured your formatter?

Comment: Please _show the contents of `stf2`_. How is is displayed when it's logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to correct the dateformatter by setting proper date formatter. first do this

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM"];
```

//it should be in the way as your string is. like if your string is 2011-Jun- 27 then fromatter should be

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

set the formatter as per your string's date format. then get the date back from this line

```
NSDate *date_ = [formatter dateFromString:stf2];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two specific problems in the code you've presented in the question.

**Format Reset**

First you do,

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
```

and then you initialize the second formatter followed by resetting the first formatter's format,

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
```

To emphasize

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
```

This should've been `formatter1` but is `formatter`.

**Date Format**

If you look at the format you've use `YYYY-MM-dd`, it looks fine. But apparent `YYYY` have a different purpose and can be different from our usual calendar year. You should use the lowercase `y` instead.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

---

And I don't think you meant this but

```
NSLog(@"date %@",[NSDate date_]);
```

should be

```
NSLog(@"date %@", date_);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "stf2" is your string, then perhaps your object *formatter* is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Below functions will be helpful to you.

"getDateTimeFromString" will take date and time as argument and it will return NSDate object.\

```
-(NSDate *)getDateTimeFromString :(NSString *)tempDate :(NSString *)tempTime{

NSString *dateValue = [tempDate stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",tempTime];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateValue];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:date] autorelease];

return date;
}
```

"getDateStringFromDate" will take NSDate as argument and it will return NSString.
So, you can NSLog that value.

```
-(NSString *)getDateStringFromDate :(NSDate *)dateValue{

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];  

 NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateValue];

 /*NSLog(@"\n"        
 "theDate: |%@| \n"
 "theTime: |%@| \n"
 , theDate, theTime);*/

return theDate;
}
```

Hope you will get the answer.